# php toronto timezone not adjusting for daylight savings

Tags: php, timezone

Edit: the problem is with the auto time stamping of the database in php. I think adding the value manually will work better. thoughts?

The php is returning the right time after the        date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

I need to somehow change the time of the database table in phpmyadmin.

I have tried the following

```
date_default_timezone_set('EST');
 or
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
or
date_default_timezone_set('EST5EDT');
```

None of them are able to provide the right time, its behind by an hour.

Not sure how to fix it.

edit: **Apologize for the formatting issues**. Thanks

Comment: sorry date_default_timezone_set('EST'); or date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto'); or date_default_timezone_set('EST5EDT');

Comment: Add that in your question not in a comment

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code - don't dump it into comments where it can't be formatted.

Comment: @SuperDJ  done. thanks.

Comment: You should use "America/Toronto".  Are you sure your server's clock is set correctly?

Comment: you need to show us how you're using this. What you posted, doesn't do much really; not on its own anyway.

Comment: I am not sure, i tried to check it in the settings for phpmyadmin but could not find anything.

Comment: I think the trouble is with the auto time stamping in the database. looking into it right now.